# Using boost to create a lambda function which always returns true

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, c++03

Suppose I have a function which takes some form of predicate:

```
void Foo( boost::function<bool(int,int,int)> predicate );
```

If I want to call it with a predicate that always returns true, I can define a helper function:

```
bool AlwaysTrue( int, int, int ) { return true; }
...
Foo( boost::bind( AlwaysTrue ) );
```

But is there anyway to call this function (possibly using boost::lambda) without having to define a separate function?

*[Edit: forgot to say: I CAN'T use C++0x]*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UncleBens commented on this in Scharron's answer, but I think it is actually the best answer so I'm stealing it (sorry UncleBens). Simply use

```
Foo(boost::lambda::constant(true));
```

As described in [the documentation for Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/lambda/s10.html#lambda.why_weak_arity), only the minimum arity of the functor is zero, the maximum arity is unlimited. So any inputs passed to the functor will simply be ignored.

Comment: I've been having a look myself and came across boost::lambda::identity... anyone know the difference? They both seem to work.

Comment: identity appears to be an undocumented template class, used in the implementation of constant (and boost::lambda::var). Much like std::mem_fun_t is the class that the helper function std::mem_fun creates and returns, except that mem_fun_t is documented and identity is not. Given that, I'd recommend using var and constant instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick example :

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void Foo( boost::function<bool(int,int,int)> predicate )
{
  std::cout << predicate(0, 0, 0) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  using namespace boost::lambda;
  Foo(true || (_1 + _2 + _3));
}
```

The trick is in `true || (_1 + _2 + _3)` where you are creating a boost lambda with 3 arguments (`_1`, `_2` and `_3`), always returning `true`.

Comment: I don't know enough about lambda to actually answer, but I assume that "Foo(true || _3)" would also work

Comment: It appears you can even do just: `Foo(constant(true));` This is nullary, but this is only the minimum arity of the functor.